# How to extract a smooth contour from a set of points in 3D?

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, smoothing, reconstruction, segmentation

I am trying to segment a 3D volume. The outcome of all my volume segmentation algorithms is a set of candidate points in 3D space. Now I need to smooth this point cloud and fit a closed surface it. My question is in two parts:

1) How can one smooth a set of rough points to get a set of soft points when demonstrated as a surface?

2) How can I fit a surface to these points to get a closed smooth shape?

Comment: Do you have the surface normals of these points? Or a simpler question, can we speak of a camera center?

Comment: @TolgaBirdal yes, my volume is a cardiac ventricle which has a circular shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like [surface reconstruction](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/04_Surface_Reconstruction.pdf) methods such as [Poisson Reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Surface_reconstruction) would fit your description. These algorithms already have the necessary smoother built-in, mainly in the form of a regularizer. To have slightly more accuracy, in general I prefer the following algorithm:

> SSD: Smooth Signed Distance Surface Reconstruction, F. Calakli and G. Taubin, Computer Graphics Forum, Vol. 30, No. 7, 2011, http://mesh.brown.edu/ssd/

There is a nice *Adaptive Solvers* repository containing many popular methods under a single roof:
https://github.com/mkazhdan/PoissonRecon

I strongly recommend to take a look at this. Here is how you would like to use it:

1. Export your point set and the surface normals to a 3D file : *sample.ply*
2. Run (make sure to play with the depth value):

   SSDRecon --in sample.ply --out sample_reconstruction.ply --depth 10 --density

This will generate a reconstruction but if you have an open surface the reconstruction will contain undesired extrapollations. So move to (3). If the surface is perfectly closed, then the output will already be good in that stage.

3. If you have an open surface then run:

   SurfaceTrimmer --in sample_reconstruction.ply --out sample_reconstruction_trimmed.ply --trim 7

Again, make sure to play with the trimming threshold. This will give you very good reconstructions such as ([taken from here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/04_Surface_Reconstruction.pdf)):

[image]

Note that for all these algorithms to work, surface normals are essential. Luckily, they can be computed from the data using [local plane fits](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php). Moreover, one also needs to ensure the correct signs of the normal directions to properly orient the surface. In the case that a single camera captures the data, the canonical choice is to flip all the surface normals so that they make an acute angle with the viewing direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tolga, does this method do the smoothing or it is just reconstructing?

Comment: It does both. Smoothness is generally a requirement for valid reconstructions. Hence, it will try to impose it.

Comment: is there any implementation of this method other than C (i.e. MATLAB or so)?

Comment: Maybe not as high quality as the toolbox above, but it is possible to find some code around. For example:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63730-surface-reconstruction-from-scattered-points-cloud

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44653-surface-reconstruction-using-implicit-polynomials

There are also python ones in case you find it easy:
https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson

There is also power-crust in Python:
https://github.com/ricebean-net/PointCloudCrust